# How to prevent merging phone's contacts and Gmail contacts on Pixel 2?

Tags: contacts, google-contacts, contact-groups, google-pixel-2, 9.0-pie

I've been using Android for 7+ years and now got a Google phone. There are several things I like but one thing which annoys me a lot is that all of my phone's contacts are now merged with Gmail contacts.

For my phone contacts, I have prefixes (Dr, Uncle, Aunt etc.) and groups. Both are now messed up. All contacts are sorted alphabetically.

From my Gmail, all people I've ever sent or received emails from, are shown in the phone contacts. I tried to show only phone contacts by deselecting other but it does not work.

How can I only display contacts from my phone's address book with groups and ignoring prefixes/suffixes in sorting order?

Comment: See if this works: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14811/96277